# Trying to make a graph data structure using a hash table (using chaining) as my vertex list

Tags: c++, graph, syntax, hashtable

I'm trying to create a data structure that stores every vertex in a hash table with separate chaining. This can easily by done using a vector to store each vertex but I want constant time searching so I'm trying to implement it using a hash table. The first node in the hash table is called `hashNode` and will consist of a `vertex` pointer, a `next` pointer of `node` type, and an int called `blockCount`. `node` type will consist of a `vertex` pointer and a `node` pointer.

The problem I'm having is I cannot access the members in my `vertex` class in my `chainingTable` class. When I try to make a `vertex` object or pointer in my `chainingTable` class, I get errors saying `vertex` is undefined. I know it's saying that because `chainingTable` has no idea `vertex` class exists but I'm having a lot trouble trying to fix it. I tried using inheritance and the friend keyword, but I don't think I'm using them right. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Here's the code that I have so far. In chainingHashTable.h,

```
#pragma once
using namespace std;

class chainingTable
{
    class node;
public:
    chainingTable(int size = 100)
        :hashTable(size), currentSize(0) {}

    struct hashNode
    {
        vertex * v;
        node * next;
        int blockCount;
    };

    struct node
    {
        vertex * v;
        node * next;
    };

    void insert(vertex * v);
    bool contains(vertex * v);
    unsigned int getNumItems();
    double averageSearchCost();

private:
    unsigned int currentSize;
    unsigned int hashFunc(string word);
    vector<hashNode> hashTable;
};

unsigned int chainingTable::hashFunc(string word)
{
    unsigned int sum = 0;
    unsigned int pow = 1;

    for (int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++)
    {
        sum = sum + word[i] * pow;
        pow = pow * 26;
    }
    return sum % hashTable.size();
}

void chainingTable::insert(vertex * v)
{

}
```

directedWeightedGraph.h:

```
#pragma once
#include "chainingHashTable.h"
using namespace std;

class directedWeightedGraph
{
    class edge;
    class vertex
    {
    public:
        string data;
        list<edge> edgeList;
        vertex(string x)
        {
            data = x;
        }
    };

    class edge
    {
    public:
        vertex * start;
        vertex * end;
        double weight;

        edge(vertex * s, vertex * e, double w)
        {
            start = s;
            end = e;
            weight = w;
        }
    };

    chainingTable vertexList;

public:
    void addVertex(string v);
    void addEdge(string s, string d, double w);
    void display();

};
```

And I know using `using namespace std` is bad practice but this program will only be used by me and is just to practice graphs and hash tables. I like the cleaner code :]

Answer (score 0):

To start with, there's no `#include directedWeightedGraph.h` in `chainingHashTable.h`. And that's just to start with...